# Freezing / poor performance of Ubuntu 20.04 on 2009 macbook

Tags: mac

TL;DR: doing basically anything in web browser etc. causes window system to freeze; I can get to tty3 to kill stuff; memory isn't the problem. what try next?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a mid-2009 13" macbook pro with 8G aftermarket RAM. It has very poor performance in a way that initially suggests hardware limitations:

- can't do anything nontrivial e.g. load gmail in Brave (Firefox similar, even Web/Epiphany)
- can't run any GUI applications while on a zoom call (occasionally Zoom alone causes a freeze)
- can't have more than one or two pdfs open in qpdfview

If I go over these rough limits, the machine freezes: mouse moves but nothing responds. In this situation I am generally able to switch over to the linux terminal using Ctrl-Alt-F3. After however long it takes to switch over, the terminal responds without any trouble and I can kill some processes and switch back, although switching back to the desktop occasionally takes awhile or refreezes.

The perplexity is that when I check `top` or `free` in these situations it sees the 8G RAM and I'm nowhere near consuming it, nor is the CPU usage obviously high (although maybe I just can't see its peaks). Pasted some log excerpts at bottom.

The freezing behavior has gotten worse over time: previously I was limited to ~2 tabs in Brave rather than ~0, and curiously when I installed a battery (after running it straight from the adapter for a while) the performance improved markedly, and for a little while I could handle ~5-10 tabs in Brave.

I'm inclined to try a lighter OS like lubuntu, but that would be more obviously indicated if the RAM were clearly the problem. I wonder if it's rather something about the window server clashing with the hardware. IIRC I'm using the basic X.org server.

I know this is a horribly anachronistic problem but would appreciate any tips as to what else to investigate, or suggestions of another OS to try!

Here are some syslog messages in the minute leading up to freeze:

```
systemd[1473]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1473]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
kernel: [ 5560.597345] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fb: trapped read at 010049d000 on channel -1 [0fedf000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]
rtkit-daemon[1000]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
```

and syslog from post-freeze when I get over to tty3 (nothing in the interim):

```
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1562]: (**) Option "fd" "33"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1562]: (II) event2  - Sleep Button: device removed
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1562]: (**) Option "fd" "29"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1562]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1562]: (**) Option "fd" "27"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1562]: (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty5.
kernel: [ 5852.262936] rfkill: input handler enabled
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1562]: (**) Option "fd" "58"
```

Comment: I suspect a problem with your memory - there’s plenty there, but it might be defective. I’d start by running a full memory test.

Comment: what graphics card do you have,there is two main types commonly used on macbook from 2009 it is nvidia g force or ati radeon.your problem sounds to me like a problem with your graphics driver(no CPU or memory problem and a graphics problem will often look like a hardware problem)maybe look for additional drivers.

Answer (score 0):

No real insights as to the cause, but I tried lubuntu and it works acceptably now.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents...
I have an old 2009 macbook. I had changed disk and RAM a some point. Even if I really love linux I had it running High Sierra for years with no other problems than the obsolescence wanted and thoroughly executed by apple on their applications.
I had a problem with openGL and Kicad installed via macports so I decided to reinstall High Sierra. The appstore High Sierra completely killed my laptop. It wouldn't start at all. There was not even a question mark at startup but the same sign there is on the incompatible applications. So I rescued it with lubuntu on an USB stick.
It works even better. All the layout is ok (except for only two keys yhat are inverted...)
I put i3wm, it is now a racing horse. Ultra fast for a 14 years old computer.